# Foreach inside Foreach in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have rec structure like this:

```
Read_PeopleAll: {PID: bytearray,Read_PropertyTax: {(PropertyID: bytearray,ReadPropertyDS: (PersonID: bytearay,PropertyID: bytearray))}}
```

Actually i am trying to access the **PropertyID** but unable to do it.

```
    a = foreach Read_PeopleAll {
        b = foreach Read_PropertyTax{

            c =  filter ReadPropertyDS by PersonID is not null;
                generate $0,c;
        };
        GENERATE $0,b;
};
dump a;
```

But i am gettign error like this:

> mismatched input '{' expecting GENERATE

*Whether i can able to use foreach inside another foreach.*

In alternative way i am able to access,

```
a = FOREACH Read_PeopleAll generate Read_PropertyTax.ReadPropertyDS;
IsValidProperty = FILTER a BY PropertyID==1.
```

Any suggestions!!!

Comment: try FLATTEN(ReadPropertyDS) instead of nested foreach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/basic.html#foreach):

> Note: FOREACH statements can be nested to two levels only. FOREACH statements that are nested to three or more levels will result in a grammar error.

You can have a FOREACH nested in a FOREACH, but you cannot have another nested operation in it.